# Conformal mapping - known points?

Tags: transformation, conformal-geometry

I have a hopefully rather simple question: I want to experiment with different geometries of flowlines and equipotential lines in a 2-Dimensional space in order to fit experimental data. Flow lines and equipotential lines are always orthogonal to each other, and hence form a basic rectangular grid in their most simple setup. I know want to transform this simple, basic rectangular grid to different shapes while preserving the angles between flow lines and equipotential lines. A bit like this, imagine the vertical lines in the non-transformed image are equipotential lines, while the horizontal ones are flow lines:

[Conformal mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqve0.png)

My online research so far has led me to the so-called 'conformal mapping' which seems to do exactly what I want, i.e. transforming the structure of the rectangular grid while preserving the angles between the grid lines.

The topic appears to be quite complex, however, so before I potentially invest days to learn the mechanisms behind it only to find out that it will not solve my problem, I wanted to ask you, who are most likely more familiar with this technique, whether what I have in mind is actually mathematically feasible:

*Is it possible to find the underlying equation/transformation mechanisms for conformal mapping of all points in the grid, if I know the old cartesian coordinates and define their respective new cartesian coordinates **of the four edge points** of this rectangular grid?*

edit: Mind, I do not require you to solve the issue, this would probably lead too far. I just want to know whether it is generally possible.

Comment: Are you in dimension 2 ?  And if you only want to preserve orthogonality between the two foliations (flowlines and equipotential) then you have a lot more choices than conformal maps. For ex, if your lines are horisontal and vertical respectively then $(x,y) \mapsto (2x,y)$ preserves orthogonality of these lines but is not conformal in the math sense (does not preserve all angles)

Comment: yes, I am in a two-dimensionals setup. Thank you, I will add this to the description.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true, but I look for more complex transformations like for example rotating one side of the rectangle by 90 degrees around its edge.

Comment: Conditions are not very clear. An example: $(r,\phi) \mapsto (r \cos \phi, r \sin \phi)$ maps horisontal and vertical lines into radial and circular. Would this be a possible map for you?

Comment: This looks like a special case to me. I am not looking for special cases, but for general cases in which four arbitrarily chosen points denote the new coordinates of the 'edges', just like in the image above. I apologize for the bad problem description, unfortunately I have not delved too far into this topic.

Comment: To me it seems the grid contains an infinite number of points (whence conditions on orthogonality). If you only want to specify conditions on 4 points in a rectangle (or more generally a finite (grid-) subset) you should be able to map them to any 4 image points by an 'orthogonal' (in your sense) transformation. But the question is a bit too vague. Also, I suspect you also want not just existence but also a way to accomplish in practice?

Comment: first of all, thank you for your continued help. I am in fact looking for a way to accomplish this in practice, but fear that the result might lead too far and be too complex to answer here. https://profile.usgs.gov/myscience/upload_folder/oc54334henry.jpg (please excuse the image quality, that was the best one I could find on short notive). I for example want to achieve something like this, from two different flow grids (one in the bottom right corner, the other stretching from left to right) combined. The potential lines arent prominent in this image, but always orthogonal to the flow lines.

Comment: Just to understand the image: The white lines (and small black arrows) correspond to flow-lines?  I am not quite sure how you see the potential lines? (not the purple ones as far as I can see? not orthogonal in the bottom-middle). What you have in mind is some description as a potential flow? like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow ?

Comment: I don't quite know what the purple lines represent here but I agree, it's not the potential. Yes, the white lines are the flow lines, and the potential lines will form perpendicular to them (not depicted here). This image represents the well-known 'Henry problem' in coastal flow, so a conformal transformation of a grid into this problem should definitely be possible. edit: oh yes, that quite looks like potential flow

Comment: What data do you have? If you have the velocity vectors at a fine grid of points it should be feasible to integrate the velocity vector field  (numerically within some approximation) to get flowlines and potential values  as well as the orthogonal vector field to get potential lines. I think this may be what you want? If you only have the direction of the velocities there are additional problems...

Comment: I basically only have the equipotential values along the top of the domain (i.e. the 'number' of equipotential lines in the base grid), and can assign any number of flow lines. The value and directions of the velocities of the flow field would depend on the geometry of the mapped field (make the grid fine enough, and you approximate a vertical and horizontal potential gradient).

Comment: So the question could perhaps be formulated: Given the potential values on the top and the picture, you would like to find a potential distribution which would give rise to the given picture for the flowlines? Is your fluid incompressible btw?

Comment: not quite, that would be rather simple, assuming I know the exact path of the potential lines. I do not know the potential values of the mapped image yet. I know how many potential lines there are in the simple, rectangular grid I start with, but I am uncertain of their path after the transformation. I want to 'bend' the flow from purely horizontal and of equal velocity to any direction I please (i.e. distort/transform the rectangular grid by defining positions of the initial grid edge points, see initial image), and then transform the entire grid accordingly.

Comment: yes, I assume the fluid is incompressible

Comment: OK, because the incompressibility implies that the divergence of $v$ vanishes so that the potential $\phi$ is harmonic whence the real part of a holomorphic  map (complex analysis).  The map you seek should then be conformal in the standard math sense preserving all angles  (closing the loop from the start ;-)

Comment: It is non-trivial to find a (genuine) conformal map. For example if $f$ is  a  conformal map  that maps a square  to a rectangle of size $L\times H$ and  the 4 corner points of the square to the 4 corner of the rectangle, then a (deep) theorem from complex analysis says that $L=H$.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh what about for mapping a square to a square all else equal?

Comment: what is this theorem?

Comment: how difficult is it?

Comment: @geocalc33 : It relies upon the Riemann mapping theorem (which you may take a look at on e.g. wikipedia). A square/rectangle may be mapped (by a Riemann map) to the unit disk. The four corners will map to four point on the boundary of the disk. You may chose 3 of those arbitrarily but the 4th will then be determined by the rest. (for this you may look at Möbius transformations of the unit disk). Hope this clarifies a bit...